# out of range in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

i have a data base where i am saving the date in DD/MM/YYYY format.
when i am running a query in my application which is

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [numbers] ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) DESC"
```

i am getting out of range error 
my data table has column like (Date_ varchar(200),number varchar(200))
but i have the similar table with similar column the table name is number 
and when i m running the same query

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [number] ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 103) DESC"
```

i am getting the desired result.
so tell me what is wrong in first query. 
and one more question i have 
i want to display results month wise in grid view.
so what will be possible table format so that i can enter date wise data in it.
like

Month      number     Month     number      Month     number            Month     number

1/1/2015   10       1/2/2015    20        1/3/2015    50 ... and so on 1/12/2015  40

2/1/2015   15       2/2/2015    25        2/3/2015     55 ...and so on  2/12/2015 67

3/1/2015   20       3/2/2015    30        3/3/2015     60 ...and so on  3/12/2015 76

here the result had to be just for last three months 
suppose if newest month is December then only October,November,December
txs in advance

Comment: please format your question

Comment: is both Table contains same set of data in Date_ column?

Comment: SELECT * FROM [numbers] ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, Date_, 101) DESC is showing the same error

Comment: SQL Server Date Range ==>January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999
Somewhere your data in Date_ field falls below or after the mentioned value and that is the reason for out-of-range error.

Comment: store Date_ in mmddyyyy format in data base. Actualy problem is when you use convert(DateTime,.. ,.. ) function. It consider source    data in mmddyyyy format.  If you want check add all the whose month and Day is less than 12(i.e 1-1-2015, 2-2-2015). Your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT() function is a general function that converts an expression of one data type to another.

In youe question you say that you have a database their you want to store dates from the program , then the **best idea is change the datatype of your column name to Date.**
Then from your .cs code

// query
     string strnewqry = "SELECT * FROM numbers";

//Build datatable

```
 DataTable datatablename=BuildDT(strnewqry);
```

// line by line checking in datatable

```
foreach (DataRow row in datatablename.Rows)
          {





string date1 = Convert.ToString(row["Columnnameofcorresponding field"]);
```

//if you want to show details in month wise then go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month(v=vs.110).aspx) then take your month value and then show it like your own way..

```
 }
```

// your BuildDT function............

```
public DataTable BuildDT(string sql)
        {
            openConnection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            da.Fill(dt);
            closeConnection();
            return dt;
        }
```